# How can I be a spinosaurus?

Tags: primal-carnage

My youngest is crazy about dinosaurs and likes to play *Primal Carnage* because of that.

He'd like to play as a spinosaurus, which should be possible, but he can't figure out how. Neither can I.

We figured out that it has something to do with the "Get to the Chopper!" mission, but we don't know what or how exactly.

**So how can he play as a spinosaurus?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the wiki](http://newprimalcarnage.wikia.com/wiki/Spinosaurus):

> Spinosaurus is currently only playable in Get To The Chopper, but the
>   developers have confirmed it will be in Team Deathmatch with the
>   release of the recode.

And [here is a guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=159880725) on how to play Spinosaurus class (steam forums).

So you have to find a "get to the chopper" server in order to play as Spinosaurus.